# Can I use "impoverished" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Public transit service  plays a considerable role in our life. The quality of these service are always being regarded as  impoverished, second class, missed departure due to wrong real-time information, etc."

Comment: You would be mixing poverty and quality.

Comment: Though you can regard the services as very poor **or** second class (and/or underfunded), you can't regard them as 'missed departure due to wrong real-time information'. You need a with-phrase or larger restructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We won't use *impoverished* to mean very poor quality. We could use *very poor* or *very bad*.

Answer (score 0):

The entire sentence is grammatical but incomprehensible. At the very least it needs some punctuation. The list of qualities includes disparate terms that cannot sensibly be lumped together:  "missed departure due to bad real-time information" refers to a particular type of incident, whereas "impoverished" or "second-class" refer to the service as a whole. You need to rephrase to clarify that you think the "missed departures" are part of what makes the bus service second-class and  "impoverished".

Having said that, I would still suggest "poor" rather than  "impoverished", unless you mean that a literal lack of funding is contributing to the poor quality of the service.